# Analyzing this method

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have a question about this method I saw on someone's code.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I know what this method does, but I don't fully understand the structure of this method. I am a little bit confused with methods, variables, objects, and parameters.

Therefore, I want to ask you if you can help me identify which is which from this method.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Is the word `Scanner` a method?
Is the word `scan` the variable?
Is `new` a modifier?

Which is which?

Comment: Actually this isn't a method.
Scanner is a class. When you do `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)` you are declaring a variable named `scan`, and creating a new instance of Scanner passing `System.in` as argument.

Comment: You have to read your courses before coming on S.O. What is that kind of question? Are we going to read your courses for you? I downvoted it.

Comment: I thought S.O was a good community for beginners to ask questions. I am reading a book and following on some video tutorials. It is just that I am still confused. So "scan" is a variable, but when am I creating a new object?

Comment: @Pablo At the right side of equation invoking `new` is creating a new instance (= object).

Comment: Ok, one more question. So if I have "int pablo = 100". Int is a class, pablo is a variable, and 100 is a parameter?

Comment: No, this case, since **int** is a primitive type, No, **int** is not a class. In Java, classes are represented by starting capital letters. int is not a class its a primitive data type.

pablo is a variable, you are right. (int, char, float, double etc) are primitives. Please refer here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Okay thank you for your help! so 100 would be a literal?

Comment: @Pablo No, `int` is declaring (indicates) the variable `pablo`'s type. Real body (object) is the value `100`, Which assigned to the variable `pablo`. So, variable `pablo` is just as an reference.

Comment: 100 is a value you are asking pablo to hold or store. After this statement, int pablo = 100;

When you say print pablo. The Java will print 100. Because you assigned mr.pablo = 100, got it?

Comment: @Pablo yes, `100` is a literal representation. I agree with ShivaShinde.

Answer (score 1):

[`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is a class name. It's used here twice - once to declare the local variable `scan`, and once to call its constructor, in conjunction with the `new` operator, to create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);**
```

Scanner - is a class predefined in java.util package.

scan - its a given name by you to utilize it in your program.

new keyword = creates a call and object of scan with Scanner

Scanner(System.in) - is constructor defined in that Scanner class which would call to get the input from the user.

Basically function is to get Input from User, since Java has provided a in built class, using it will make your life easier by just creating a **scan** object of Scanner class.

Answer (score 0):

- `Scanner` is a class
- `scan` is a variable of type `Scanner`
- `new Scanner(System.in)` invokes a constructor of class `Scanner` creating a new object of that type, which is assigned to the variable `scan`. `System.in` is a parameter passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Scanner scan** = new Scanner(System.in);

The above statement has three parts (discussed in detail below):

**Declaration:** The code set in bold are all variable declarations that associate a variable name with an object type.

**Instantiation:** The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.

**Initialization:** The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

**Scanner** is here a class, which is imported from java.util.Scanner;

Now, coming to **System.in**, are you familiar with **System.out**?

So, **System** is a class, here **in** and **out** refers to keyboard input and

Comment: @Pablo, in the same way, in the above example, you are asking **Scanner scan = new Scanner();**, you are asking **scan** to hold new Scanner ();

The slight difference is **int** in above case is primitive data type and **Scanner** in this case is a class.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is the class. A class is a piece of reusable code that has certain attributes or characteristics. A class can be "used" multiple times. When you use the class Scanner, you create an instance of that class, a specific "version" of the Scanner class. This you have given the name "scan", but it could be anything. So that java knows you are creating a new instance of the Scanner class and not calling a previous instantiation of the Scanner class, you use the reserved word "new". You then have to tell java what the class of the new object is that you are instantiating (I know, you already did, but that is the syntax). The brackets indicate a parameter. This is something used to create the object (of class Scanner) with the correct attributes. In this instance you are saying the Scanner called "scan" must fill itself with a value from the system input (System.in). Then you have a "variable" called "scan" that is of the type Scanner who's values come from "System.in". I really hope that helped. Please excuse any bad format or broken rules, this is my first answer.